# How to buy a Final Blast

Tags: jetpack-joyride

How do I purchase a final blast in Jetpack Joyride? I've gone through virtually all things in the stash.

Comment: You find them in Utilities, like Head Start and Quick Revive. "Costs 1000 coins for one use and 4000 coins for a 5 pack"

Comment: But where is utilities?

Comment: It's a tile in the Stash.

Comment: It's not there. There's only clothing, jetpacks, ride upgrades, get coins, ect

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Sure I have one

Comment: @PrismWiz4rd Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

It is found in The Stash, in the upper right hand corner. It is found in Utilities.

[image: The Staaaaaaaash]

Once tap Utilities, you will get into a menu. Scroll down and you will see this!

[image: ULTILADASJDH]

As you can see, there are the Final Blast (Three Pack), and there is also just one above.